# Github - committing changes on existing local branch to new remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have a "dev" git branch.  I made some code changes locally.  I haven't committed them to the remote "dev" branch. Now that I'm halfway through the changes, I don't want to commit the local changes to same remote branch.  I'd like to create a new branch called "over_here" and commit the changes there.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Do you want to commit to a new branch or push your local commits onto a new branch. The difference is, do you have multiple commits you want to move to the new branch or just your current changes?

Comment: Commit to a new branch. I haven't made any commits at all on the local dev branch (so just current changes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your remote has standard git name `origin`:

```
git checkout -b over_here
git push origin over_here
```

Depending on if you need to reset your `dev` branch back to `origin/dev` state you could also execute

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

UPDATE: Above was written assuming you have some changes commited. As you told in comments that you didn't commit anything to local `dev` branch - you need to checkout new branch right now:

```
git checkout -b over_here
```

Now your changes still here, but you're on the newly created branch. So you're ready to commit your local changes:

```
git commit -m 'my local changes to over_here branch'
```

Now these changes are in your local repo only. If you want to push them into remote repository (probably github) - you should execute:

```
git push origin over_here
```

It will create new branch in the remote repository and commit your changes there.

Comment: Pardons for the ignorance, but how can I tell if my remote has standard git name origin?  And what's origin refer to?

Comment: Use the first option and if you want to keep the branch local just omit the push command

Comment: `git remote` will show you list of remotes you have configured. `git remote show _remote-name_` will show you details about the remote with name `_remote-name_` which should be equal to one of names you get from first command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push your branch `foo` to branch `bar` on remote `origin`, you can use `git push origin foo:bar`. `git push origin foo` is shorthand for `git push origin foo:foo`

If you use `git push --set-upstream origin foo:bar`, you can then use just `git push` and `git pull` on that branch without having to specify remote and branch names.